# How to record a user action and replay when he returns back?

Tags: java, android, back-stack, onsaveinstancestate

I wants to know is there a way to save the user action done in app and replay them when he returns back. Let me explain that clearly.

Like in my app I provided a lot of free PDFs to users. But to download them the user should make a login.

But I realised if I ask the user to login at first without showing any preview of my things they won't feel great so I decided to allow user skip login and check the preview of he likes a PDF and wants to download it then I will check and ask user to login and after he logs in the intent should be taken to where he left. Like when logged in the pdf should start download.

So how can I save the user's previous actions and guide him to where he left.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. I looked for it from past 2 days and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think a memento pattern would do what you want here,
if I recall correctly the memento pattern has for objective to 'save' all changements done to an object.
Were you to successfully implement it, you would just have to save the memento savepoint in a json file and load the json when the user come back (i guess?)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern

Comment: That explains of what I want clearly. So how can I do that in Android. In most of apps today we can see the app allows to use it without a login but to use its core features we have to make a proper login. Take Google Chrome app when we leave the app and clears it from recent apps and later opens it. Then it will open the last page we visited (if it isn't removed). That's what I'm looking to implement

Comment: to save an object to json https://stackoverflow.com/a/5571130/12424449
save the object when the app is closed
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17132388/12424449